# Broadcast Ubuntu network connection over WiFi from Ethernet

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

Is there any way to broadcast the internet connection from Ethernet to WiFi on Ubuntu?

Comment: sounds like it should be possible.  sometimes people call it a "ad-hoc" network.

Comment: yeah it's possible, but when I tried it a few versions back it was a pain. I think I had to install a network card manager tool. I don't really remember.

Comment: See my updates answer, perhaps this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An access point (Usually a router can be configured as an access point) can do this. It recieves ethernet and allows WiFi devices to connect to it.

***UPDATE:***

I finally get what you mean, try this:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=376283

Comment: I  know, we have a WiFi router but I want to use the Ubuntu computer as a router where the internet signal is weak.

Comment: -1 missed the point of the question